# Inserting data each day into SQL Server from csv

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I need to insert large ammount of data each day into my SQL Server database. The data is inserted from the file, where rows represent data from this year, and some of these rows  may be changed, while new rows are added to the file each day, so I need to check if some row is changed in the file and to update database and always to insert new rows.

So, what approach do you recommend (clear database/bulk insert, read line-by-line and insert in C#, ssis, etc.) ?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to create a `Delta` writing / Inserting to a DB from a .CSV file is not very difficult. there are many different approaches to doing this.. I would personally create a Class with the file structure as well as what fields you want inserted into the DB. then create a stored procedure that would do either the Insert or the Update. also show what you have tried thus far..

Comment: How much data is "large"? What percentage is new vs. updated? Do you have hardware performance constraints?  Can this be done overnight? Once the data is in there, is it primarily a report resource?  There are a lot of factors to iron out before a recommendation makes sense.

Comment: I'm in the planning phase, so for now we have our ASP.NET app and the file cvs is being created. The file is around 1.000.000 lines at the end of the year, when it is full. It's almost 99% new rows each day, some of the rows can be changed. No, I don't have hardware performance constraints and it can be done overnight. The data imported is used only as a report resource. Just to say, we are currently using two technologies for data import/export, console app, which calls Web service to do export and SSIS import, but I'm not satisfied with SSIS, because of database and data tools versioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would just drop the table and reload the CSV every night using SSIS, then create fresh indexes as part of the nightly job.
If each CSV contains all of the relevant information, then this is the simplest way to go.
No reason to fool around with update/merge logic that I can see.

Plus, given your aversion to SSIS, a straight table load with index creation should be very easy to implement in a C# script.

**SSIS Route:**

First, build the first load as demonstrated [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/).

Next, right click on the table is SSMS and generate the create script for that table.

Then, create an Execute SQL task in SSIS that runs before the load task.  That SQL task will run the following 2 pieces of code `drop table <your table name>`, followed by the create table script you copied earlier.

Finally (and optionally), create an Execute SQL task that runs after the data load task that will create any needed indexes.  Since I know nothing about your data, I'd recommend a nonclustered index that includes all of the columns that you use for parameters in your report, such as `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SalesPerson_SalesQuota_SalesYTD ON Sales.SalesPerson (SalesQuota, SalesYTD);`

While not a perfectly tuned solution, it should suffice for what you are trying to do and be easy to maintain.

I may be able to add screenshots later.

Comment: When you say: "straight table load with index creation", do you mean on some kind of a "bulk insert into tables" ?

Comment: Exactly.  Bulk insert into a table that you recreate each night, then create indexes on any of the columns that you use as parameters for your reports.

Comment: O.K. Do you have any example to direct me to ?

Comment: Great, thanks ! Where can I find SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio for Microsoft Sql Server 2008 R2 ?

Comment: It should be included with your server license, depending on version. Perhaps you should ask your administrator?

Comment: We have full version of SQL Server 2008 R2 licensed, I just need to find how to install Business Intelligence Development Studio.

Comment: Can I install Business Intelligence Development Studio for Microsoft Sql Server 2008 R2 on my local machine where I have SQL Server 2012 express, without installing SQL Server 2008 R2 instance ? And if yes, how ?

Comment: I believe so, but its not my area of expertise.  I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: I found it. Can you add some screenshots here ?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approach depends on how data is being used by application for the moment I would suggest following steps:
Create schedule a job to upload data into Temp Table(s)

1. Bulk Insert into Temp Table
2. Insert New rows form Temp Table to Main Table
3. Update existing rows from Temp to Main Table

or You can delete existing rows by comparing Temp Table to Main Table and Then Build Insert every thing from Temp Table to Main Table.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an "upsert".  SQL server supports [the MERGE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) that achieves this.  You could feed your csv data into a temp table & then MERGE it into your destination table w/that syntax.  Probably SSIS would let you set that up in a neat job.